# using AJAX to get data from Bottlepy server

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, bottle

I'm trying to retrieve json data from a bottlepy server onto a webpage. I was trying to implement a basic version first so tried with just strings. But nothing seems to be happening. Here is the code -

HTML(including js) -

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<script>
function print()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('http://localhost:8080/check', function(result){
            alert('success');
            $('#main').html(result);
        });
    });
}

print();
</script></body>
</html>
```

The python code -

```
from bottle import Bottle, route, get,request, response, run, template

app = Bottle()

@app.hook('after_request')
def enable_cors():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

# a simple json test main page
str = "Hello"
@route('/')                   #irrelevant to this question. Used this to check server...
def test():
    return template('file', str)

@app.get('/check')
def showAll():
    return str

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

What do I have to do to access the data on the server? 
Note : The HTML is a separate file, and I want the code to work irrespective of the location of the HTML.

Also, if this is not possible, how can I do it with the help of templates?

Comment: Can you access `/check` from the browser? You probably need to use `run(app=app, host=...)`. Consider removing the `run(...)` completely, and instead use `python -m bottle --reload --debug <myscriptnamewithoutextension>:app` to develop.

Comment: yes, /check loads perfectly on the browser if I change app.get() to route().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from some confusion with the bottle app.

Bottle creates a default app for you whenever you use `@route` [(more on this)](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#default-app), and reuses this default app implicitly on subsequent calls. This default app behavior is present in many functions (including `hook` and `run`).

The point is:

```
app = Bottle() # creates an explicit app

@route('/')    # adds the route to the default app

@app.hook('after-request')  # adds the hook to the explicit app

run(...) # runs the default app, the hook is not used
```

To solve your problem you have two options:

- remove any mention of the explicit app;
- always use the app explicitly

I found using the app explicitly made it easier to create sub-apps and much more clear in general what was going on.

New code:

```
import bottle
from bottle import response, template, run

app = bottle.Bottle()

@app.hook('after_request')
def enable_cors():
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

# a simple json test main page
str = "Hello"
@app.route('/')                   #irrelevant to this question. Used this to check server...
def test():
    return template('file', str)

@app.get('/check')
def showAll():
    return str

run(app=app, host='localhost', port=8080)
```